# How to display data in HTML from http get call using angularJS 1.6

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

I am able to console the result of the http call but when I bind it so that I can view on the html page I am unable to do it. Can someone help me with this? I am posting the controller code and the html below.

Controller code

```
           //module
        var weatherApp = angular.module('weatherApp',['ngRoute' , 'ngResource']);


        //Routes
        //http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?APPID=metric

        weatherApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

            $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
              templateUrl:'pages/home.htm',
              controller:'homeController'
            })
            .when('/forecast', {
              templateUrl:'pages/forecast.htm',
              controller:'forecastController'
            });
        });

        //services
        weatherApp.service('cityService' ,function() {
          this.city ="San Jose, CA";
        });


        //controllers
        weatherApp.controller('homeController' ,['$scope', 'cityService', function($scope , cityService) {

          $scope.city = cityService.city;
          $scope.$watch('city' , function () {
            cityService.city = $scope.city;
          });
        }]);

          $scope.city = cityService.city;
  console.log($scope.city);
  $http({
      url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?APPID==metric",
      method: "GET",
      params: {q: $scope.city, cnt:2}
   }).then(function(response){
        $scope.weatherResults = response.data; 
        console.log($scope.weatherResults);
   });

}]);
```

HTML CODE For Index.htm

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="weatherApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/navbar.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
   <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- NAVBAR -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Accurate Weather</a>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<!-- NAVBAR ENDS-->

<div class="container">
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Code for Forecast.html

```
Forecast for {{city}}   <!-- THIS WORKS -->

{{ weatherResult.cnt }}  <!-- THIS DOES NOT WORK -->
```

Code for home.htm (EVERYTHING WORKS FINE HERE JUST POSTING FOR THE SAKE OF CLARITY)

```
<div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h4>Forecast by city</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" ng-model="city" class="form-control" />
    </div>
      <a href="/weatherApp/index.htm#!/forecast" class="btn btn-primary">Get forecast </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[console output correctly displays the objects:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct5oO.png)

Comment: This is rather unclear. Can you clarify what exactly isn't working as intended?

Comment: make sure above html code is in the controller

Comment: can you post your controller or share some fiddle?

Comment: Edited the post. Can you check what is wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try and initialize `$scope.weatherResult` as an empty object in your controller so that AngularJS can watch it correctly.

Comment: Hi There, I edited the post and added whole of the code. I tried what you suggested but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. Can suggest something else?

Answer (score 0):

Just put this assigning inside `$scope.apply` to notify angular engine that data was changes asynchronously so it should be processed correctly

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.weatherResult = response.data; //IF I LOG THIS IT WORKS
});
```

Also good to add check that gigest cycle is not in progress now

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
  //$digest or $apply
}
```

Comment: Hi There, I edited the post and added whole of the code. I tried what you suggested but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. Can suggest something else?

Comment: This code is executed? Maybe some inline angular errors in console? Could you add console.log in apply directly to print `weatherResult` after assigning? It print correct value?

Comment: Hi VladimB, The only thing that is missing from this code is my AppId from the  URL to which I make the get request as I have removed it for safety reasons. Yes, if  I console.log it, I get absolutely the right value.

Comment: Added the console output at the end.

Comment: Maybe you can create live fiddle as seems everething looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Angular's inbuilt 2-way data binding does not work on http responses which is a known issue. Use `$timeout` to manually kick in the 2-way data binding and thereby initiating the digest cycle.

```
$scope.getWeather= function(){
    $http({
        url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?AP&units=metric",
        method: "GET",
        params: {q: $scope.city, cnt:2}
 })
    .then(function(response){
           $timeout(function(){
             $scope.weatherResult = response.data; 
          }, 0);

    });
 }
}]);
```

Note the `$timeout` timer is set at 0ms to immediately kick in the digest cycle.

Comment: Hi There, I edited the post and added whole of the code. I tried what you suggested but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. Can suggest something else?

Answer (score 0):

Correct Code posted. I was assigning the http get call to $scope.variable, I just removed it and it started working. Thanks